# CS0165 issued in VS2019 but not VS2022

Tags: c#

Consider this dummy program in a project targeting .NET Framework 4.8:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CS0165
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Function(null);
        }

        static string Function(IDictionary<string, string> dict)
        {
            if (dict?.TryGetValue("A", out var value1) ?? false)
                return value1;  // <-- error in VS2019

            if(dict?.TryGetValue("A", out var value2) == true)
                return value2;  // <-- error in VS2019

            if (dict != null && dict.TryGetValue("A", out var value3))
                return value3;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This builds without error for me in Visual Studio 2022, but my coworker gets error CS0165 (use of unassigned local variable) when building in Visual Studio 2019.  The csc.exe command-line (visible by setting VS' MSBuild output level to Detailed) is identical on his and mine (especially "/langversion:7.3") except for the path to csc.exe.  His csc.exe version is "3.11.0-4.22108.8 (d9bef045)" and mine is "4.5.2-3.23171.7 (d17f7415)".

The answer to this question [Why the output is CS0165 when using a Null-Conditional Operator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32572) on the Roslyn Github site would say to me that the rules for determining whether a variable is assigned or not are part of the language spec, so whether it's definitely assigned or an error should be fixed in the language spec and not vary based on a new version of the compiler being smarter.  Is that true?  And shouldn't it be true that if I compile with language version 7.3 without errors that it should build without errors on any version of the compiler as long as it supports and is using language version 7.3?  Or is this a compiler bug in the older/newer version?

Comment: The last if doesn't trigger the same error in VS2019?

Comment: Looks like the compiler in VS2022 is now aware of this: _"However, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns."_ (From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)